# Is reading a X11 Property of type UTF8_STRING guaranteed to end with NULL?

Tags: x11, xlib, icccm

I have the following code:

```
static Atom _NET_WM_NAME = XInternAtom( display, "_NET_WM_NAME", false );

unsigned char* wm_data = NULL;
Atom wm_type;
int wm_format;
unsigned long wm_nitems, wm_bytes;

std::string title;

int ret = XGetWindowProperty( display, window, _NET_WM_NAME, 0, 512,
    false, utf8_string, &wm_type, &wm_format, &wm_nitems, &wm_bytes, &wm_data);

if( ret == Success && wm_nitems != 0 && wm_data != NULL ) {
    title = (const char*)wm_data;  // [1]
}
```

The `_NET_WM_NAME` property is a `UTF8_STRING`, as per the [spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s05.html)

So, in my code above, `[1]` assumes that the received data will always be NULL terminated.
The code as it is works, but the returned byte amount (`wm_nitems`) does not include the NULL terminator, it is always the same as the actual string length. This is what makes me uncertain.

So my questions are:

1. Is guaranteed that a read of a `UTF8_STRING` property will always return the string INCLUDING the NULL terminator?
2. If so, why is the NULL terminator not included as part of the `wm_nitems` count?
3. Can somebody point where this is specified in the spec?
4. And in particular, is the above snippet correct for reading the `_NET_WM_NAME` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[XGetWindowProperty](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XGetWindowProperty.html)

> "XGetWindowProperty() always allocates one extra byte in prop_return (even if the property is zero length) and sets it to zero so that simple properties consisting of characters do not have to be copied into yet another string before use."

---

`wm_nitems`

> `nitems_return`: Returns the actual number of 8-bit, 16-bit, or 32-bit items stored in the prop_return data

Why should the null terminator count as data. It is the courtesy of `XGetWindowProperty` to automagically return a null terminated string (see above), but the `nul` character is not part of the actual data (e.g., it is absolutely possible to set the window name without an ending `nul` char).

To put it differently: `strlen` doesn't count the terminating null character either, right?

---

Another thing, C strings are **null** terminated character arrays. The symbol `NULL` is the **null** pointer and has a special meaning in the C environment (see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/NULL).

- `'\0'` is of type `char`
- `NULL` is of type `void*` (implementation-defined, could also be `0`)

Comment: `wm_net_name_atom` -> typo while adapting the code to the web. Edited.

Comment: about the `null`s. Yes, I know. I am referring here to the `null` terminator character (`\0`)

Comment: I know, i just wanted to point it out.

Comment: the first part of your answer addresses all my questions. `XGetWindowProperty` adds it. It seems to not be required by the spec, and since it is not part of the property it does not count as a property byte. I went to the spec, instead of reading the function's documentation :(

Comment: "I went to the spec" The spec for Xlib is the programming manual and it says that an extra byte is allocated. What other spec did you go to?